# Can't get Flask App to run after Re-Organizing Project Directory

Tags: python, flask, importerror, error-logging, project-organization

I started building my flask app with a very basic structure detailed [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/), basically everything in one directory. As I have added more dependencies to my project, the need to separate my app into individual components has come up. Here is a look at how I have everything organized right now:

```
Real-Life-Application
│
├── App
│   ├── UI
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── main.css
│   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   ├── album_placeholder.jpeg
│   │   │   │   ├── header.jpeg
│   │   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   │   └── javascript
│   │   │       ├── create.js
│   │   │       └── tracks.js
│   │   └── templates
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── create.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── information.html
│   │       └── tracks.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── authenticate.py
│   ├── db_actions.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── services.py
│   └── user_operations.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── Testing
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── testing.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── authenticate.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── config.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── main.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── services.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── user_operations.cpython-39.pyc
├── config.py
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── setup.py
```

My problem is that after running the basic commands `export FLASK_APP=run.py` & `flask run` I get the following error:
`Error: While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised.`

I can't figure out what is causing this error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the contents of run.py:

```
from App import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Contents of App/ **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import config
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import sqlalchemy

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    app.secret_key = app.config['CLIENT_SECRET']

    # connect to local instance of mysqlDB server
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

    # create session and base declarative
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    Base = declarative_base()

    # make sure user table is created
    from App.user_operations import User
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # schedule updates for the TopTracks playlists
    from App.services import updatePlaylists
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(updatePlaylists, trigger='interval', days=1)
    scheduler.start()

    import App.routes
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    
    return app
```

Contents of App/routes.py:

```
import logging
import time

# Flask Imports
from flask import (jsonify, make_response, redirect, render_template,
                   request, session)

# Local Imports
from authenticate import createStateKey, getToken
from App import app
from services import (addTracksPlaylist, createPlaylist, getAllTopTracks,
                      getRecommendedTracks, getTopTracksURI,searchSpotify,
                      createRadarChart, getLikedTrackIds, likedTrackIdsDataFrame,
                      normalizeDf)
from user_operations import (addUser, getUserInformation)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    """ 
    Homepage.
    """
    return render_template('index.html')

# More route definitions come after this of course.
```

Contents of config.py

```
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback'
RESPONSE_TYPE = 'code'
GRANT_TYPE = 'authorization_code'
TOKEN_URL = ''
SCOPE = 'user-read-email'
AUTHORIZATION = 'Authorization: Basic *<base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>*'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_NAME = 'DB'
```

Again, I really appreciate anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas can you point me to some documentation on how to implement this?

Comment: it make no sense to read another documentation. After reading you may create another structure which will not work. Better try to repair current structure. But this need FULL error message to see what is the problem - but you show only last line of error.

Comment: @furas even with development mode on, this is all i am getting for the error message

Comment: strange: when I run your incomplete project then I get the same error but much longer `Error: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/furas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "flask-folders-structure/run.py", line 12, in <module>
    from App import create_app
  File "flask-folders-structure/App/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`

Comment: @furas Im not sure what the project is missing in order to run properly. Many basic tutorials have the same structure my project has.

Comment: my error message in `Traceback` shows: `No module named 'config'` - so I know that I'm missing `config`, next time it show error message w different name and I know that I'm missing another file, and this way step-by-step I can correct code. And this is why I ask for FULL error message. If you don't get `Traceback` with information then it is big problem - you may try to use `print()` in files to see which file was loaded and see in which file is problem. You may also try to run `python run.py` and maybe it will show different messages. And forget structures in tutorials. They don't help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @furas. My issue was not in any of the files in the original question. I had to run `python run.py` in order to get a more in depth logging response that included a Traceback report. The Traceback I received uncovered a Circular Import I had within my application after restructuring.

At times simply running `flask run` would provide a Traceback to the problem, but Im guessing that when the issue is with the initialization of the app `flask run` is not enough